# Can't log into PokeGo. Not accepting any of my possible email accounts!

Tags: pokemon-go

So I was having trouble logging in, like most everyone seems to be and decided to try logging out - now I can't get back in. I believe I'm having a different problem than others: when I log in using the Trainer way, it threatens to lock me out of my account if I go over the amount of tries. I swear I didn't use Google to sign up. Logging in with Google says my password is incorrect. And when I try to recover my info using the Trainer recovery, it tells me none of my email accounts are tied to my PokeGo! Is there any way to get my information? Please, I don't want to start all over.

Answer (score 1):

If you were playing on a PTC account, you have to login with the PTC option using your username, not your email address.

If you were playing on a Google account, you have to login with Google using the appropriate email address and password.

Comment: That is what I've tried. It does say "username" and that's what I have done. But when I asked PTC to send me a new password in case I miss typed, it told me that there is no account tied to my emails. Shouldn't I have a confirmation email that was sent after my signup? I've checked my inboxes and yes, also my junk email folder to no avail.

Comment: Have you ever registered a PTC account?

Comment: I thought I had when I signed up on the PokeGo app.

Comment: If you haven't registered, you used your Google account to play.

Comment: Doesn't matter. My account doesn't exist somehow. Even having reset my password, entering the correct info signs me up for a new account. Thank you for your input anyway.